# Datareader to List

Tags: c#, list, datareader

Im trying add values to list with this method;

```
    public List<Product> GetAll()
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select * from products",Connection.connection);
        Connection.connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
   
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Product product = new Product
            {
                ProductId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ProductId"]),
                StockCode = reader["StockCode"].ToString(),
                Barcode = reader["Barcode"].ToString(),
                ProductName = reader["ProductName"].ToString()             
            };
            products.Add(product);
        }
            
            reader.Close();
            if (command.Connection.State==ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                command.Connection.Close();
            }   
        return products;
      
    }
```

I want only 4 column in this product table

[but coming all columns like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Whx2r.png)

its normal ?

Comment: You get the columns that your query ask for. "SELECT *" return all columns. Change your query to "Select ProductId, StockCode, Barcode, ProductName from products"

Comment: if you want only 4 columns to return, why do you select all? Also, inline sql is not a good idea

Comment: SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select StockCode,Barcode,ProductName from Products  ", Connection.ConnectionOpen);
I try with this but still same 
Thanks for answers

Answer (score 0):

The way you are connect to the database is not very proper,
always use "using". That way, everything gets closed automatically.

Also try only getting the things from the sql server you really need.
I made(and also tested) an example:

```
public List<Product> GetAll()
    {
        string command = "SELECT ProductId, StockCode, Barcode, ProductName FROM products";
        List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

        Connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, Connection))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    products.Add(
                        new Product {
                            ProductId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ProductId"]),
                            StockCode = reader["StockCode"].ToString(),
                            Barcode = reader["Barcode"].ToString(),
                            ProductName = reader["ProductName"].ToString()
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
        }

        return products;
    }
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vh5iK.png)

If you call the function it would make sense to put it in a try catch block since it is not uncommon for sql connections having problems.

For reference:
[my horrible mssql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DB6hq.png) and
[my product class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTKXk.png)

Comment: thanks for answer, I used like this but still same coming all columns.

Comment: For me it works, seems to me like you have the option on to automatically create new columns(in regard to the class you used as itemsource)
What are you using(wpf,winform,etc)?

Comment: Im using winform. I quess create columns for gridview

Comment: Then you probably have to turn of automatic column creation in the gridview settings and create the columns manually in the interface beforehand .